# Appengine Deployment to cloud

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I need to deploy my backend module to cloud but when I try to deploy I am getting the below error .I have searched a lot but could not find any solution for this.

Please let me know the procedure step by step if you have any idea.Thanks in Advance..Below is the error which I get

[image: Error when I try to deploy]

Error when I try to login in Android Studio:[image]

Comment: are you logged into your account in android studio?

Comment: No i did not log in.Actually i don't know how to login'

Comment: top right corner is a google login

Comment: I am getting an error as shown above and next its saying "please login via opened browser".

Comment: Does anyone have an update on this??Searching for past one week to deploy my applengine to cloud but unable to login to android studio.

Comment: first login with your google account in studio

Comment: @pravin When I login Iam getting the error as attached above

Comment: after login please check your path i.e. deploy to is correct

Comment: Where do you receive the message error box? In browser or Android Studio? What browser and what OS are you using?

Comment: @Morales I am receiving that message in Android Studio.Browser which iam using is google chrome and OS is windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Just goto : https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and click continue this going to allow access from other servers.